# SwiftUI - Remove space over navigation title

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationview

Is there a way to remove extra space over navigation title (scribbled it in Red in below screenshot). I am working with iOS 15.

[image]

***Code:***

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation

struct ContentView: View {
    let names = ["Holly", "Josh", "Rhonda", "Ted"]
    @State private var searchText = ""
    
    /// A site name filter phrase entered by the user.
    @State private var query: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationView {
                VStack {
                    List {
                        ForEach(searchResults, id: \.self) { name in
                            Text(name)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .searchable(
                    text: $query,
                    placement: .navigationBarDrawer(displayMode: .always),
                    prompt: "search"
                )
                .navigationTitle("Explore")
                .background(Color.gray)
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(Color.gray)
    }
    
    var searchResults: [String] {
        if searchText.isEmpty {
            return names
        } else {
            return names.filter { $0.contains(searchText) }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For a large title, that is by design. If you don't want the space, you can use `.navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)`, but the title would be smaller. Otherwise you have to roll your own, I think.

Comment: Ah ok. I tried... setting ".navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)" did remove the space, but the title moves in center. I guess I will have roll on my own and maybe create a custom search bar/text field with custom list and custom title. As it is in between search bar and list, I have to add a horizontally scrolling list of items, which I am unsure if I can achieve with this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a large title, that is by design. If you don't want the space, you can use `.navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)`, but the title would be smaller.

[image]

You would need to create your own views if you want a big title, *and* no space above it.

Though this is a bit hacky, one way I came up with is putting the title in the `toolbar`:

```
.toolbar(content: {
    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
        Text("Explore")
            .bold()
            .font(.largeTitle)
    }
})
.padding(.top, -20) // removes the extra top padding added by not having a navigation title
```

Of course, doing it this way loses the "title turns small when scrolling down" feature.

Result:

[image]

Comment: Hmm... This works great. I should be good without turning the title to small during scroll. I was also able to add a horizontal scrolling list between search bar and vertical list of names. And I wanted a button on the extreme right of "Explore", so was able to use "navigationBarTrailing" ToolBarItem for it. Thanks @Sweeper!!!